# How to synchronize 2 Oxyplot graphs?

Tags: wpf, prism, oxyplot

I have a WPF application that is being used to show 2 graphs that I've created using Oxyplot. Both these graphs are independent - they have their own Views and ViewModels and receive data from different sources.

```
    UserControl
    |
    |--- ContentControl
    |     |
    |     |--- ViewA (Contains 1 graph) --- ViewModelA --- SourceA
    |
    |
    |--- ContentControl
          |
          |--- ViewB (Contains another graph) --- ViewModelB --- SourceB
```

As and when ViewModelA receives data from SourceA, I add the data to the Series and then call Model.InvalidatePlot(true). Same goes for ViewModelB and SourceB.

The only thing common between the data for both graphs is the time. SourceA and SourceB send data that may be only a few milliseconds to a few seconds spaced apart.

So here's what I need to achieve - how do I ensure that the DateTimeAxis of the two graphs are always synchronized? At any given point in time, I need to show the same Minimum and same Maximum value on the X axis of both the graphs.

I have come across the AxisChanged event where I can use the event from 1 graph and set the same values on the other graph. But in my case, I'm not sure how I can use this since my graphs are in separate classes. Also, the case I have described is quite a simple one. I may end up with up to 9 graphs during the lifetime of the application and the order of creation of graphs can vary. So I don't think I can consider one graph as the primary and get all the others to follow this one.

Any ideas on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: You'll need a parent view model holding your `Minimum` and `Maximum` values, so your charts are in sync, and then children view models (ViewModelA, ViewModelB) containing specific data for each chart.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I've come across the similar issue. I have the multiple parallel axes in one Plot, and need them to be in sync when user zoom or pan them.
Oxyplot team did not implement this functionality yet (see: https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/issues/86, https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/issues/59). But there is rather simple workaround:
you need to treat one axis as main, and update the other axis like:

```
AxisT.AxisChanged += AxisT_AxisChanged;

private void AxisT_AxisChanged(object sender, AxisChangedEventArgs e)
{
  switch (e.ChangeType) {
    case AxisChangeTypes.Reset:
      AxisD.Reset();
      break;
    case AxisChangeTypes.Zoom:
    case AxisChangeTypes.Pan:
      AxisD.AbsoluteMinimum = AxisT.ActualMinimum;
      AxisD.AbsoluteMaximum = AxisT.ActualMaximum;
      AxisD.Minimum = AxisT.ActualMinimum;
      AxisD.Maximum = AxisT.ActualMaximum;
      break;
  }
}
```

In this approach there is no difference are axis in the same plot or different ones. If you have diffenent scales on axis then apply scale ratio like AxisD.AbsoluteMinimum = AxisT.ActualMinimum * ratio;

AxisChangedEventArgs contains DeltaMinimum and DeltaMaximum values, but I did not find the way to easily apply them to other axis, so it is simpler just to use ActualMinimum and ActualMaximum values.

Actually, you can set the same handler for the other axis, just make sure that update loop stops when you are setting the same value twice.

And the comment by @jsanalytics allows you to beautify this solution in MVVM way.